# Android datepicker two-way databinding

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I'm trying to use 2-way databinding for a datepicker. Looking at [two-way databinding guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way#two-way-attributes), it shows platform has built-in support for datepicker's attributes: android:year/month/day, but I couldn't find these attributes in the xml (e.g. unknown attribute: android:hour). Am I misreading the guide and what is needed to implement 2 way binding for a datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with the Android Studio, but datepicker two-way binding is working properly even with the "unknown attribute" warning.

xml:

```
android:day="@={viewModel.day}"
android:month="@={viewModel.month}"
android:onDateChanged="@{(v, year, month, day) -> viewModel.onDateChanged(year, month, day)}"
android:year="@={viewModel.year}"
```

In ViewModel:

```
val year = MutableLiveData<Int>()
val month = MutableLiveData<Int>()
val day = MutableLiveData<Int>()

fun onDateChanged(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
    dateTime.value =
        dateTime.value?.withYear(year)?.withMonth(month + 1)?.withDayOfMonth((day))
}
```